# как очистить консоль через время? С#

Tags: c#

мне нужно написать фразу "Привет" и через 2секунды очистить и вписать "Мой друг"

Comment: Если удалось разобраться, то чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.WriteLine("Привет");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("Мой друг");
```

Comment: Console.Clear();

Comment: Старайтесь не использовать `Thread.Sleep`. Нужно крайне осознанно подходить к использованию данного метода (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815895/why-is-thread-sleep-so-harmful). Это не значит, что `Thread.Sleep` - плохо. Просто нужно понимать, какие последствия это ведёт за собой. Конечно, в данной ситуации, это не будет критично, но всё же лучше воспользуйтесь, например, `Timer`, как альтернативой. Так же, при указании какого-либо времени пользуйтесь `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)`

Comment: @Frehzy раз пошла такая пьянка, то тогда уж лучше `await Task.Delay(2000);`. Всяко проще будет выглядеть, чем таймер, а в консоли и `Sleep` сойдет, так как там нет UI потока, приморозив который приложение подвиснет.

Comment: @aepot Да, согласен, `Delay` будет получше, чем `Timer`. Опять же, в данном случае блокировка потока на 2 секунды не будет критична, т.к. тут нет каких сложных многопоточных методов, UI и прочего-прочего. Просто, каждый раз, когда я вижу `Thread.Sleep`, у меня возникают вьетнамские флешбеки и немного дёргается глаз из-за того, как я раньше совмещал lock и Thread.Sleep и получал по голове за такие приколы с потоками. Сейчас 1000 и 1 раз задаю себе вопрос - "А точно тут нельзя без этого?"

Comment: @Frehzy флешбэки - это `Application.DoEvents()`, и ведь работало всё...

Answer (score 0):

```
// в инпорт [using System.Threading.Tasks;]
static async void test_write()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Привет");
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Мой друг");
}
// данный метод позволяет его выполнить без держалки в работе кода .NET 4.5
```